# How to set a Windows Environmental Variable as XML Attribute

Tags: xml, windows

Is there a way to set a windows environmental variable (such as COMPUTERNAME) to an attribute in xml? If so what would the syntax look like?

For instance
<name = "COMPUTERNAME">

Comment: an environment variable is just a string.  You can put whatever you want in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 3 (perhaps XSLT 2 too) there is a function `environment-variable` you can call so e.g.

```
<test name="{environment-variable('PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE')}"/>
```

on my system, when run in an XSLT 3 stylesheet with e.g. Saxon 10, outputs e.g. `<test name="AMD64"/>`.

So `<computer name="{environment-variable('COMPUTERNAME')}"/>` with XSLT 3 might do what you want.